# What kind of leafy house plant is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I was given the plant as a gift.  Started out small and has grown to almost 6 1/2 feet tall and has sprouted off spring.

Original
[image: Original plant]

Offspring:
[image: Offspring]
Google reverse image search resulted in "Houseplant".  Not very helpful.

I have since removed the dead leaves from the plant.

Comment: Future visitors might appreciate for reference the somewhat similar (though *different*) species found in this post: [What is difference between “Syngonium” & “Pothos”?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58638/16866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a [Dieffenbachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieffenbachia), see also this question & answer from Gardening.SE:

https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9765/what-is-this-thick-stemmed-houseplant-with-variegated-leaves

though I am not sure of the species, it could be *[Dieffenbachia seguine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieffenbachia_seguine)* which shows a similar coloration and is one of the taller species (I believe some of the others stay bushy).

On the linked answer, @TeresaMcgH warns:

> By the way, one of the common names for this plant is "dumb cane" because the sap can cause numbness and swelling in the mouth and throat if ingested. So watch pets and small kids around it if you have such at home.

Comment: Bryan is correct: this is a _Dieffenbachia_. Also, I would like to emphasize the warning: it may not only cause numbness, but can be dangerously toxic. If you search scientific literature, several serious cases are documented. Those include necrotic tissue (fingers, to the bone!) and other severe systemic health issues.